File search program
I’m writing a program to search files on a computer and I’m faced with the problem that the search takes a very long time to complete, in my opinion, how can I speed up the code?
I use an SSD, I don’t know the exact number of files, but out of 465 GB, 279 GB are occupied
Visual Studio has Maximum optimization (speed priority) (/O2)
void searchFiles(const std::string& searchQuery, const std::string& rootDir, std::vector<std::string>& results) {
    std::queue<fs::path> dirs;
    dirs.push(rootDir);

    while (!dirs.empty()) {
        fs::path currentDir = dirs.front();
        dirs.pop();

        try {
            for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(currentDir)) {
                if (fs::is_directory(entry)) {
                    dirs.push(entry.path());
                }
                else {
                    if (entry.path().filename().string().find(searchQuery) != std::string::npos) {
                        results.push_back(entry.path().string());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) { }
    }
}

Here is the code where the function is called
void ScannerFile::ScanningFile()
{

    for (size_t i = 0; i < defaultPath.size(); i++)
    {
        searchFiles(defaultPath[i], "C:\\", ModuleManager::resultFile);
    }
}

I tried to rewrite it somehow, but there was no point, the speed still did not change
For example, a video file was searched for 94 seconds
C:\\Users\\mgrr\\Videos\\Desktop\\Desktop 2024.10.20 - 16.03.16.04.mp4
C:\\Users\\mgrr\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Recent\\Desktop 2024.10.20 - 16.03.16.04.lnk
C:\\Users\\mgrr\\Videos\\Desktop\\Desktop 2024.10.20 - 16.03.16.04.mp4
C:\\Users\\mgrr\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Recent\\Desktop 2024.10.20 - 16.03.16.04.lnk
C:\\Users\\mgrr\\Videos\\Desktop\\Desktop 2024.10.20 - 16.03.16.04.mp4
C:\\Users\\mgrr\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Recent\\Desktop 2024.10.20 - 16.03.16.04.lnk

Execution time: 94.0131 seconds


You still didn't post a minimal reproducible example. What is defaultPath? How many elements does it contain?

There is one thing that can easily be optimized: you call searchFiles once for each element in defaultPath, this is very inefficient, because the execution time will be proportional to the number of elements in defaultPath. Instead you should pass defaultPath to searchFiles and search for all elements in defaultPath in the else block. That way the execution time won't depend anymore on the number of elements in defaulPatht.

Other than that you could use multithreading

The main problem with code like this is that it is latency bound and path resolution is also expensive. Each operation is done serially and one at a time. The latency of SSD is quite significant (though better than HDD). Some OS provide async features for that. This is OS dependent. Generic API are inefficient (including the libc). Sometimes the FS can slow thing down or the SSD driver itself too. Besides, not all SSDs are equivalent in term of latency. The latency of SATA SSD can be much higher than NVMe ones not to mention a huge gap between different hardware/firmwares.

So, yes, multithreading can help (assuming there is no lock in the drivers which happen sometimes), but it is better to use an async API if possible. Mixing async and multiple threads can often results in optimal performance compared to async or multithreading alone (you also need to tune the number of threads regarding the target platform).

Just to see whether 94 seconds is "slow", compare against rg.exe -. --glob "*some_pattern*" --threads 1 C:\ 

Is there some reason why "dir *.mp4 /s" from the command line won't do what you want? That is limited by console IO speed on my system and about 20s for 512GB and a modest number of files found. Much slower for many files found.

@MartinBrown on my computer on some pretty large directory with lots of subdirectories and files"dir somename /s" took about 7 seconds (26 files found), whereas the OP's code took about 11 seconds, also for 26 filres found.

Profile.  Find out where most of the time is spent in your program.  Optimize that section.  For fastest service, directly call the OS functions.

I guess it'd be much simpler to use std::recursive_directory_iterator instead. Moreover, since each std::directory_entry invokes string operations to calculate its path, the performance can be upto 50 times slower than native API.

In situations like this, a systematic approach is essential to identify the bottlenecks in your code. You can use C++ profiling tools to pinpoint which parts of your code are causing slowdowns. Visual Studio includes a built-in C++ profiler, or you can choose from other options listed here:
What's your favorite profiling tool (for C++)
Additionally, there are many YouTube tutorials on C++ code profiling. Once you’ve identified one or more bottlenecks, you can address them by either optimizing the existing code or implementing solutions like multithreading.
